# Why was this question asking on how to get from a given location to a given area closed as not focus enough?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

I see that [How can I find the fastest path by car to reach a US state from a given US location?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/159426/1810) was closed as:

> Closed. This question needs to be more focused. It is not currently accepting answers.

The question seems focused to me: it is asking for the fastest path to get from a given location to a given area by car.

Why was it closed a needing more focused? None of the closevoters left a comment,  so I don't know what kind of focus they have in mind.

Comment: The usual answer, several people voted to close it. If you disagree, vote to re-open.

Comment: @Willeke Understanding the close voters' rationale could help prevent future close votes.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with Franck. Personally I don't think it's a *good* question, but I don't understand how it "needs to be more focused". There's exactly one clearly defined question, what are people finding unclear about it? Voting to re-open might or might not work, but certainly doesn't clarify what the actual problem is that people saw with the question. Which means OP can't try to fix the problem or avoid making the same mistake in future questions.